# Is it possible to change your voice?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

Ok so I have been playing Star Wars the Old Republic for at least a year now. But right now I need the help of a seasoned SWTOR veteran. Is there any way to change your character's voice without changing their gender?

Comment: I think voice is based off of gender and class, along with helmet, nothing else. I haven't played recently, but I don't think there is anything else to change it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shadow's comment is exactly correct.  There is no way to change an existing character's voice other than the slight modulation provided by some helmets.  Voice is determined by gender and base class.